# Moodle Guest access mobile

Tags: moodle, moodle-mobile

I've activated the option to show the button "login as guest" but the button doesn't show in app mobile (in web the button shows)

Somebody know's how enable the login guest button in app mobile?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Moodle WebService architecture does not support guest users thats why Guest Access is not available on Moodle Mobile App.

There is an open feature request for this -  https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MOBILE-2299